# Select not working ;

Tags: php, mysql, session

i have problem, i can't run select this when I using session in `WHERE p.post_by ==  '{$_SESSION['user_id']}`, although i can echo session['user_id'] in screen, if i using `WHERE p.post_by <> '{$_SESSION['user_id']}` then SELECT working, can you help me?

```
$sql="SELECT p.id,p.post_convert,p.post_id,p.post_title,p.post_by, p.post_time,p.post_view,p.post_catelogy,
p.post_content,p.post_summary,p.post_picture, c.menu_id,c.menu_title,u.id_user,u.username,u.info 
FROM post p, category c, user u 
WHERE p.post_by = '{$_SESSION['user_id']} ' && p.post_catelogy = c.menu_id  
ORDER BY p.id DESC";
```

Comment: what is the value of `$_SESSION['user_id']` ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using double ==, no need here:

```
WHERE p.post_by ==  '{$_SESSION['user_id']} '
```

This should be:

```
WHERE p.post_by =  '{$_SESSION['user_id']}'
```

Note that, `WHERE p.post_by <>` is working because its valid.

Also remove extra space from `'{$_SESSION['user_id']} '` it will consider in condition like:

```
WHERE p.post_by = 'Test ' // which is not equal to 'Test'
```

**Modified Query:**

```
$sql="SELECT p.id,p.post_convert,p.post_id,p.post_title,p.post_by, p.post_time,p.post_view,p.post_catelogy,
p.post_content,p.post_summary,p.post_picture, c.menu_id,c.menu_title,u.id_user,u.username,u.info 
FROM post p, category c, user u 
WHERE p.post_by = '{$_SESSION['user_id']}' && p.post_catelogy = c.menu_id  
ORDER BY p.id DESC";
```

Comment: @BiHíp: ok, what are u getting in `$_SESSION['user_id']`?

Comment: so sorry because i reply comments of you now, `$_SESSION` when login success and i need `$_SESSION['user_id']` to print listings posts ^^
value of session is " US02"

Comment: `SELECT p.id,p.post_convert,p.post_id,p.post_title,p.post_by, p.post_time,p.post_view,p.post_catelogy,
p.post_content,p.post_summary,p.post_picture, c.menu_id,c.menu_title,u.id_user,u.username,u.info 
FROM post p, category c, user u 
WHERE p.post_by = 'US02' && p.post_catelogy = c.menu_id  
ORDER BY p.id DESC` run this on phpmyadmin @BiHíp

Comment: waoooo... `$_SESSION` this worked :3 thank you because support for me ^^

Answer (score 0):

try to concatenate the session id:

```
where p.post_by = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."'
```